# Use environment variable in a quote

Tags: environment-variables, docker

I'm trying to use an **environment variable** in my Docker config file (/etc/sysconfig/docker), the particular line is:

```
other_args="--insecure-registry $PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL:5000"
```

Notice `PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL` is the environment variable I need to use. However I've also tried:

```
other_args="--insecure-registry ${PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL}:5000"
other_args="--insecure-registry \$PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL:5000"
other_args="--insecure-registry '$PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL':5000"
other_args="--insecure-registry ${PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL}_*:5000"
```

None seemed to work so far. Please clue me in. Thanks!

Comment: did you restart the docker daemon ? and when this `PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL` is set ?

Comment: Yes I restarted Docker daemon after config file update. PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL is set as environment variable before it is used. Anyway, refer to my answer I had a workaround.

Comment: it can be solved without workaround, which os do u use ? I can verify it.

Comment: CentOS 6.5. After starting docker service with `other_args="--insecure-registry $PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL:5000"` in `/etc/sysconfig/docker`, `ps -ef | grep docker` shows this: `/usr/bin/docker -d --insecure-registry :5000` If you notice carefully you'll spot $PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL was resolved into empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I had a workaround for this. Instead of using environment variable in the config file, I ran a script to  **echo** the argument and append to the config file.

`echo other_args=\"--insecure-registry $PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL:5000\" >> /etc/sysconfig/docker`